# handling cluster modules in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fork, cluster-computing, child-process

I'm trying to learn cluster module and I come across this piece of code I just cant get my mind around it. First it fork childs with child_process module and there it use cluster.fork().process , I've used both cluster module and child_process in an express web-server separately i know cluster module works a load balancer.

But I cant get the idea of using them together. and there also something else, cluster is listening to those worker process and when ever a disconnect and possibly exit event is emitted to master it reforked a process , but here is the question lets assume email worker crashes and the master is going to fork it again how does it know it should fork email ? I mean shouldn't it pass an id which I cant see in this code.

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // fork child process for notif/sms/email worker
  global.smsWorker = require("child_process").fork("./smsWorker");
  global.emailWorker = require("child_process").fork("./emailWorker");
  global.notifiWorker = require("child_process").fork("./notifWorker");

  // fork application workers
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    var worker = cluster.fork().process;
    console.log("worker started. process id %s", worker.pid);
  }
  // if application worker gets disconnected, start new one.
  cluster.on("disconnect", function(worker) {
    console.error("Worker disconnect: " + worker.id);
    var newWorker = cluster.fork().process;
    console.log("Worker started. Process id %s", newWorker.pid);
  });
} else {
  callback(cluster);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but here is the question lets assume email worker crashes and the
>   master is going to fork it again how does it know it should fork email
>   ? I mean shouldn't it pass an id which I cant see in this code.

The `disconnect` event it is listening to comes from the cluster-specific code, not a generic process listener.  So, that `disconnect` event only fires when one of the cluster child processes exits.  If you have some other child processes processing email, then when one of those crashes, it would not trigger this `disconnect` event.  You would have to monitor that child_process yourself separately from within the code that started it.

You can see where the monitoring is for the `cluster.on('disconnect', ...)` event here in the [cluster source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js#L163).

Also, I should mention that the cluster module is when you want pure horizontal scaling where all new processes are sharing the exact same work, each taking new incoming connections in turn.  The cluster module is not for firing up a specific worker to carry out a specific task.  For that, you would use either the [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) module (to fire up a thread) or the [child_process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) (to fire up a new child process with a specific purpose)